# graphviz plugin in confluence showing text as boxes

Tags: graphviz, confluence

I'm creating a graph database diagram using the graphviz plugin but the text in the description shows up as squares. How do I fix? Is it an encoding issue? I'm using the png option with graphviz and not the svg option. SVG option does show text, but it has other issues.

It even shows boxes with the default graph viz diagram as shown attached.

[image]

Comment: Are you using the default font or did you override it?

Comment: http://www.graphviz.org/doc/fontfaq.txt

Comment: I didn't configure the confluence server, using the confluence on the corporate intranet.

Comment: I had a similar problem on my ubuntu machine, and solved it by installing fontconfig: https://howtoinstall.co/en/fontconfig